# What is the Oracle equivalent of the SQL Server command line utility (sqlcmd.exe)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, oracle11g

What is the Oracle equivalent of the SQL Server command line utility, sqlcmd.exe, to execute SQL that is contained within a file? I need to do this from a Windows machine.

Besides installing the the oracle Client, is there anything else that needs to be installed to run this from Windows?

Comment: Not sure whether this is strictly on-topic ... anyway, I believe `sqlplus.exe` will meet your needs, and it is available as part of the [Oracle Database Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html).

Comment: @HarryJohnston You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Oracle Database Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) includes `sqlplus.exe` which provides a command-line interface to run SQL commands.